# Does my internet speed matter?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, exit-relays, circuit, guard-node, speed

Does my internet speed matter if I use same circuit, nodes/hops? 
There are 3 PC's:
1st one is connected to 100Mbps internet speed 
2nd 500Mbps internet speed
3rd 1Gbps internet speed
In case all of them use same circuit the average ratio of HTTP request durations will be the same or will differ ? 
If downloading something through Tor - the download speed in Tor network will be same or higher internet speed means higher speed in Tor ?

Answer (score 0):

Your download speed will be bottlenecked by the speed of the slowest link. If the speed is truly terrible, you can try creating a different circuit but realize that the slowness is one of the costs for anonymity.